# Best approach to take on half dead string of pearls

Tags: houseplants, indoors, plant-care

Long story short, I placed something light on top of my basket of string of pearls and then forgot to take it off. I believe that is what killed the top ends of each string, as you can see in the picture. I’m stumped on the best way to move forward - is the plant still salvageable or will it slowly die? Can I cut each string and propagate it? 
[image: stringofpearls]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look too bad from here and may recover reasonably well, but probably the pot is a bit overcrowded and is calling for prompt renewal. It's an excellent idea to take some cuttings (lots of YouTube videos showing this process) which should root readily in well drained soil and bright conditions.

Comment: Unfortunately the top of every string is dead because I placed something on the top. I’ve trimmed them all and placed the fresh ends into the soil. I hope that works!